# How to get a list of the latest messages between users

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm looking to get a list of all messages between users but only the latest message sent by either `user A` or `user B` in the database these fields are `fromUser` and `toUser`

I need a list of the latest message between each users.

so for example:

| fromUser | toUser | message | date (this would be a valid date iso time string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | "Hi there" | 6 days ago |
| 1 | 3 | "Hello bro" | 1 day ago |
| 2 | 1 | "Hi admin" | 5 minutes ago |

I want to get the following list

| userPair | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2, 1 | "Hi admin" |
| 1, 3 | "Hello bro" |

but I want the userPair to only contain the other user and not my own user, my own user id would be 1

I've tried quite a few things

Example 1

```php
$results = DB::table("messages")
        ->selectRaw('GREATEST("fromUser", "toUser") as user1, LEAST("fromUser", "toUser") as user2, MAX(created_at) AS maxdate')
        ->where('fromUser', $user->id)
        ->orWhere('toUser', $user->id)
        ->groupByRaw('GREATEST("fromUser", "toUser"), LEAST("fromUser", "toUser")')
        ->get()
        ->flatten();
```

Example 2

```php
$results = ModelsMessages::where(function($query)use($user){
            $query->where('toUser', $user->id)->orWhere('fromUser', $user->id)->orderBy("created_at");
        })->select("toUser", "fromUser")->distinct()->get();
```

Example 3

```php
 $results = DB::table('messages')
        ->select('*')
        ->where(function($query) use($user){
            ->where('fromUser', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('toUser', $user->id)
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(1)
        ->unionAll(function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->select('*')
                ->from('messages')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->limit(1);
        })
        ->get()->flatten();
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: ``Message::where('fromUser', $user->id)->orWhere('toUser', $user->id)->latest()->get()``

Comment: This question has enough debugging details to be answered, I don't understand why it got closed. If you think that this question does not show research effort, there's voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fix the partitioning properly, you can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` to order on your date column. Then it's sufficient to filter out records that have a ranking higher than 1.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY CASE WHEN fromuser > touser THEN fromuser ELSE touser END, 
                            CASE WHEN fromuser > touser THEN touser ELSE fromuser END
               ORDER     BY date) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT CONCAT(fromuser, ', ', touser) AS userpair, 
       message
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

| userpair | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2, 1 | "Hi admin" |
| 1, 3 | "Hello bro" |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tPhGvWWvgzPB61JfEAwtUc/0).

Comment: I had to make some changes, but it worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query.

`auth()->user()->id` is the id you want to filter in userPair .

```php
use DB;

Message::orderBy('date', 'desc')
  ->where(function($q){
    $q->where('fromUser', auth()->user()->id) 
      ->orWheere('toUser', auth()->user()->id);
  })
  ->select(
    'message', 
    DB::raw("IF(fromUser = ?, toUser, fromUser) as user", [auth()->user()->id]),
    'CONCATENATE(fromUser, ",", toUser) as users' // If you want to select the exact pair you have specified in question
  )
  ->get();
```

Comment: `Builder::selectRaw()` is preferred over using `Builder::select()` with `DB::raw()` these days.